# Mac Mini 2018 Kernel panic bug_type 210 after Security Update 2020-002

Tags: mac-mini, bug, kernel-panic, macos

Since installing the Mojave Security Update 2020-002 I do get a message that my Mac Mini 2018 was restarted because of a problem even I shut it down normally. The Mac Mini 2018 was running fine for 3 months. The Apple Hardware Check does not show any errors. Also tried to reset SMC and PRAM.

[image: Your computer was restarted because of a problem]

Is this a known bug? Just curios wether Mac mini 2018 users who also installed Apple's Security Update 2020-002 do see the same error message?

**November 15th, 2020**: I am pleased to confirm that BridgeOS firmware version 18.16.12561 fixes the Kernel panic bug_type 210 on a Mac mini 2018. Take a look at my answer.

**October 19th, 2020**: Apple released *Security Update 2020-005* and macOS Supplemental Update. The bug has STILL NOT been fixed on macOS Mojave 10.4.6. On cold reboot "Your system was restarted because of a problem" message still shows up.  I

**July 16th, 2020**: Apple released *Security Update 2020-004*. The bug has STILL NOT been fixed on macOS Mojave 10.4.6. On cold reboot "Your system was restarted because of a problem" message still shows up. No status update on Apple Bug Report. I am kind of surprise on how Apple seems to ignore Mac mini users. They messed up the T2 chip BridgeOS and simply don't care. I guess this bug will never be fixed. Users should rather invest in a new Mac mini model with their latests Apple processor. I am not willing to spent more money on any Mac mini.

**Update May 28, 2020:** Apple released *Security Update 2020-003*. However the bug has NOT been fixed on macOS Mojave 10.4.6. On cold reboot "Your system was restarted because of a problem" message **still shows up**.
No status update on Apple Bug Report. Mac Mini users do not seem be relevant for Apple. Such a disappointment.

**Update April 24, 2020:** **Workaround: Do not use Safari until Apple fixes the bug. Also make sure to set the default browser to Firefox, Chrome, Brave... which prevents opening Safari by accident. The shutdown message no longer shows upon a cold boot.**

**Update April 11, 2020:** I did some further testing regarding my initial issue. I have restored from a previous system backup using SuperDuper. This backup clone does NOT include the Security Update 2020-002 Mojave and Safari 13.1. Surprisingly the shutdown message still shows up sporadically when I power on the Mac mini. I have completely shut down my Mac mini 2018 around 10 times. I have waited 5-10 minutes. 4 of 10 times the crash report showed up. It's really difficult to debug. What's interesting is the macOS Mojave Software Update does not show the Security Update 2020-002. So it seems to be already applied. I guess it is definitely related to the T2 BridgeOS Update or other firmware settings which have been patched during the Security Update 2020-002. Restoring from a 4 weeks old system backup does not resolved my issue.

This is a really bummer. I wish Apple would spend more time on testing. So far I haven't heard back from my Apple Bug Report #FB7646566.

**Update April 2, 2020:** I did a clean install macOS Mojave 10.14.6 without the Security Update 2020-002. As soon as I install the Security Update 2020-002 the annoying crash report shows up when the Mac mini has been shut down.

The Diagnostic Report reads as follows:
{"caused_by":"bridgeos","macos_system_state":"shutdown","bug_type":"210","os_version":"Bridge OS 4.4 (17P4263)","timestamp":"2020-03-28 22:10:39.00 +0000","incident_id":"907CAD79-9364-4588-A25A-3810D0E72F8F"}
{
"build" : "Bridge OS 4.4 (17P4263)",
"product" : "iBridge2,5",
"kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Mon Mar  2 20:38:56 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010",
"incident" : "907CAD79-9364-4588-A25A-3810D0E72F8F",
"crashReporterKey" : "c0dec0dec0dec0dec0dec0dec0dec0dec0de0001"

Comment: I have a Mini 2018 and have not seen any problems after the Security Update. I'm still on Mojave, if that's relevant.

Comment: iBridge is the "T2" security chip - https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/T8012 [tbh, I have no idea what that signifies, but at least that's what it is that's not enjoying the update].

Comment: @benwiggy  Did you completely shut down your Mac Mini 2018?

Comment: Shutdown is compulsory to install the update.

Comment: @benwiggy I wasn't referring to the update. The error message shows up everytime I press the power button. It does NOT show up on reboot. Could you check again?

Comment: My Mac mini 2018 is experiencing the same issue after Security Update 2020-002.

Comment: @howdytom I don't see any problems.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my Mac mini (2018) since upgrading to the security update.

Comment: @howdytom Thanks for updating your progress. So it seems like we just need to wait for a fix from Apple then.

Comment: Thanks for all the updates. I have this issue too and this post helped me understand the why's.

Comment: There is a 2020-003 security update, released today, at over 2GB.

Comment: The bug has NOT been fixed with Security Update 2020-003.

Comment: Do you have f.lux installed by any chance? I still have to observe it a little longer but I'm confident that the issue has disappeared for me since I closed the f.lux service runnign in the background.

Comment: I don't use any f.lux service. This bug is reproducible on a clean install.

Comment: There is a security update 2020-004 !!!

Comment: @benwiggy: I have updated my original post. The bug has STILL NOT been fixed on macOS Mojave 10.4.6 and Security Update 2020-004!

Comment: Has anyone tried Security Update 2020-005 yet?

Comment: yeah, I have updated my original post. Security Update 2020-005 and macOS Supplemental Update does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh god that's terrible. Thanks for letting us know though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pleased to confirm that BridgeOS firmware *version 18.16.12561* fixes the Kernel panic bug_type 210 on a Mac mini 2018.

**Solution:**
Installing Big Sur on a separate volumes updates the BridgeOS firmware version 18.16.12561. When you reboot back into Mojave you do no longer experience the error message on cold reboot. After 7 months Apple finally fixed the issue. Apple never replied on any of my Bug Reports.

*Note:* Installing Security Update 2020-006 on macOS Mojave 10.4.6 does not fix the Kernel panic bug_type 210. You have to install Big Sur on external drive prior going back to your Mojave installation.

Comment: regarding Security Update 2020-006 I have read that it does or does not update bridgeOS, perhaps depending on the version of bridgeOS on the device. ie. if your Mac mini is original it will update it, but if you've already done the Big Sur fix (like me) it won't (and didn't) update bridgeOS.

Comment: That's correct. Which bridgeOS version are running. Did you install a Big Sur Beta release? Did install a clean installation a external drive?

Comment: 18P50347c, from either Big Sur DP4/PB1 7 Aug 2020. I installed it on a new (to me) 2018 Mac mini before I erased everything completely and replaced with Mojave before migrating my old laptop. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406574/bridgeos-not-updating

Comment: I haven't installed any security update after 2020-002, but today I installed 2020-005 and it updated the BridgeOS to 18.16.12561. After installing 2020-005, the update for 2020-006 became available and now I'm gonna install the new version.

Comment: And no more error after 2020-006 even after using Safari. Finally 

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm similar issues post Security Update 2020-002 on a 2018 Mac Mini runnign 10.14.6.

- A few days later I power it down. On restart refuses to boot normally, taken to Internet restore, which ends in Error -1008F.
- After clearing NVRAM it boots normally.
- Left to sleep overnight
- In the morning, it had shutdown and on starting up normally I received an ‘Unexpected Shutdown message, the crash log showed a panic with iBridge.

Reported to Apple with Feedback Assistant

Update: Security Update 2020-003 has updated Bridge OS so hopefully fixes the issue....

Comment: Categorically NOT fixed by Security Update 2020-003 :( So frustrating. Left it sleeping overnight, woke up to Mac Mini in 'off' state and a panic report message upon startup. 

`{"caused_by":"bridgeos","macos_version":"Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G5033)","os_version":"Bridge OS 4.5 (17P5290)","macos_system_state":"sleep","incident_id":"A667FC6A-A14F-44FD-A2C4-35F782EC24B4","timestamp":"2020-05-27 21:42:59.00 +0000","bug_type":"210"}
{
  "build" : "Bridge OS 4.5 (17P5290)",
  "product" : "iBridge2,5",`

Answer (score 3):

I also have this after every reboot/restart after running the 2020-002 security update on my Mac Mini 2018. Odd thing is, I first ran the update on a Mac OS that was booted  from my external SSD (which I occasionally boot from for music production) and after I did this I also got the error after booting from my internal SSD, which had not yet been updated. So I don't know what this install did to the T2 chip but it's apparently regardless of wether you're running on internal or external SSD, and it seems to have affected the hardware rather than the Mac OS installation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. So glad I am not alone with this annoying bug. I have submitted a Apple Bug Report.

Answer (score 3):

<s>In my case **security update #3 fixed this issue**. Can't reproduce it by opening Safari or putting the Mac to sleep.</s> After a clean shutdown and startup the error shows. So no fix indeed. Shabby.

---

Can't comment, so just wanted to state that **the workaround from @howdytom works (update April 24, 2020)**.

I'm going to use Chromium (`brew cask install chromium`) until a Safari update comes and fixes the issue.

---

Same here. Macmini8,1 since Security Update 2020-002 (Mojave).

In my case the first thing that happened was that I had no screen signal, the update "broke" the thunderbolt port where the screen is connected. The port came to life again after manually resetting the NVRAM.

After that, every time my Mac goes into a deep sleep it restarts. Not sure if it's when it goes to sleep or at the moment I wake it up. That is very annoying and critical since any work I have opened gets lost. After reading this thread tested that a shutdown results in the same error and report.

I'm reading carefully [this how-to](https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-restore-bridgeos-on-a-t2-mac-how-to-put-a-mac-into-dfu-mode), although I only have this Mac right now so I can't try. I suppose downgrading as @howdytom did to 10.14.6 (18G3020) from late January and do not apply the #2 security update is the only workaround right now.

I've already filled a report using the Feedback Assistant on March 31. No reply yet, as expected. I'll update the report with this thread link. Please report it to Apple too, the more we are the faster they'll fix that. In case you do (or did) please link to my report ID: FB7646497

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sharing your insights. So far I haven't any reply on my bug report as well.

Answer (score 3):

Same here in the Netherlands with my Mac Mini 2018 since the Security Update 2020-002 (Mojave). 
The Security Update results in the Crash reports:
{"caused_by":"bridgeos","macos_system_state":"shutdown","bug_type":"210","os_version":"Bridge OS 4.4 (17P4263)"

After a reinstall of Mojave 10.14.6 from a bootable USB and applying the Security Update 2020-002 the crash reports changed a little in: {"caused_by":"unknown","macos_system_state":"running","bug_type":"210","os_version":"Bridge OS 4.4 (17P4263)"

The Mac Mini is stable and does all daily tasks during working from home in this COVID-19 time. I have completed an Apple feedback report and wait for any solution...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Hopefully Apple will address this bug