# bridgeOS not updating?

Tags: mojave, mac-mini, t2

I just updated my Mojave machine to Security Update 2020-006 but my bridgeOS has not updated, it remains on 18P50347c which I got when I tried Big Sur DP4/PB1 on 7 August 2020?

I don't have any other Macs so "downgrading (from beta to release) bridgeOS using Apple Configurator 2" isn't an option.

How can I get the latest bridgeOS on my Mojave Mac mini?

Comment: Are you upgrading or downgrading? Both words are in the body make it slightly confusing.

Comment: Also, I feel I’m starting to belong to a Dell / Windows hobby club worrying about firmware . . . https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/16/which-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using-version-5/

Comment: I want to move from the beta bridgeOS I have to the release version. The "downgrade" process will do this once the latest release version is newer than the one you have. I agree it's ridiculous and confusing and I'm disappointed it is even something I need to do. That's New Apple, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you have previously installed a beta release, it looks like the bridgeOS update is skipped. Try to install the latest macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29) release on a external drive.

Comment: I don't have a suitable external drive (this Mac mini originally had Big Sur beta on it before I flattened and reverted back to Mojave) but will try to get a drive with 35GB free (I have a spare 32GB SSD, which is annoying).

Answer (score -2):

I have had decent success downloading the full installer. Usually that works without going to recovery but sometimes that is easier for people. But I only go to newer bridge, not regress so you might need someone to hack together a regression step if the full installer doesn’t get your the briegeOS you seek.

Your process is the same to [retry an install if Big Sur (or any oter upgrade) fails.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406256/5472)

```
softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.14.6
```

Or you could go to the Mojave install page:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Comment: this command doesn't work, it just shows me the `softwareupdate` help text. google says it was introduced in Catalina.

Comment: Mojave download and install via App Store link did not update it — in fact it took me back to a system pre Security Update 2020-005! Urgh, a lot of re-upgrading to do.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the full installer lags. You may be waiting for the next major release cycle, unfortunately @MattSephton